# Is it possible to find a an interval of values of $x$ in the domain of convergence such that $f(x)\ne 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let us consider the following series:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (-1)^nn^x\ln^2 n$$

where $x\in \mathbb R$.

**My question** is: Is it possible to find an interval of values of $x$ in the domain of convergence such that $f(x)\ne 0$ ?

Comment: For $x > 1$, the series won't converge, so...

Comment: @mathworker21: in the domain of convergence such that $f(x)\ne 0$?

Comment: @mathworker21 No real reason to omitt the fact that the series converges if and only if $x<0$.

Comment: @mathworker21: Is it possible to conclude that the series does not vanish for all $x<0$.

Comment: 'tis the second derivative of the Dirichlet eta function, so one may as well just find inflection points of that function?

Comment: @E.James I was saying $f(x) \not = 0$ for $x > 1$ since it doesn't even converge.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{\ln n}n$ is strictly decreasing from $n=2$ on. 
Therefore the convergence for $x\le -2$ follows fro Leibniz' criterion and it suffices to check the first few summands to obtain an explicit bound - that will easily lead to $f(x)\ne 0$.

Comment: Actually, the derivative of $y^\alpha\ln^2y$ is definitely negative for all $\alpha<0$, so you have that the series converges if and only if $x<0$. I don't know if this changes the answer though.

Comment: @  G. Sassatelli: Is it possible to conclude that the series does not vanish for all $x<0$.

Comment: @E.James:  Why not begin by applying Hagen's approach at $x=-1$?